# Are SQL views references, or a stored syntax to be evaluated at runtime?

Tags: sql

As the question implies I'm not sure where SQL views are evaluated once during the session and then store the references, or are they store syntax which is evaluated at runtime? While it seems that it's second as same view can yield different results if the table which this view queries from is modified, It is confusing as for example when using alias for a table inside the view, this alias is not recognized when referring to it afterwards in the same statement which uses the view.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is just stored code  .. the result is always obtained  at runtime.. the select column alias are not available  at the moment of the where clause evaluation  ..  the select clause is eavluated  after the where clause.

Comment: First of all, each engine is free to process them in any way they prefer. Having said that, they are typically "expanded" in the main query, but not as literal text; that's why the same alias can live in the main query and in the view definition as well. As for materialized views, that's a different story.

Comment: Normal views, each time that you select from it then it'll run the query that's defined in the view.  But there exist also [Materialized Views](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) in some of the RDBMS. Those actually store data and get a periodic refresh.

Comment: A view is a *logical* construct, not physical (except for when *materialized* as mentioned); When you utilize a view, the query optimizer will parse and expand the view definition into the outer query, how this is done depends on how the view is used and can quite often be optimized, ie excluding elements that are not used by the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored view (`CREATE VIEW AS`) gets parsed at creation time, but is not much more than the mere code. When you run a query that uses this view, the whole query gets parsed and the code executed. (The exception to this is a materialized view as mentioned by LukStorms and The Impaler in the request comments.)

This query:

```
select from mytable t where id <= 100;
```

can be used as a view such:

```
select * from (select from mytable t where id <= 100) myview;
```

or such:

```
with myview as (select from mytable t where id <= 100)
select * from myview;
```

or such:

```
create view myview as select from mytable t where id <= 100;

select * from myview;
```

In neither option are you able to access the table alias t in the main query. It is hidden inside the subquery. The main query only sees the view name and its result.